# ajax calender extender month name display

Tags: asp.net, ajax, date, calendar

i have added an extender to the text box to select date. The date it shows the number of the corresponing month. is there any way to get the month name instead of the month number? for eg i get as 04-04-13 i want it as 04-Apr-13. Thanks in advance

the code i have is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInvDate" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="88px"
        ontextchanged="txtInvDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtInvDate_CalendarExtender"
        runat="server" TargetControlID="txtInvDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following format:

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtInvDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtInvDate" 
    Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" >
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

[**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

particularly: [**The "MMM" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier)

Note that it depends on the current culture on the server.